# Dart outdated dependencies are not showing in red color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I ran

```
flutter pub outdated
```

However, the outdated dependencies aren't showing in red color. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run

```
dart pub outdated
```

[image]